# PC to PC transfer of files with rj45 cable - avoiding complications

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-xp

I wish to transfer a great many files form one PC to another, one running win-xp-32, the other running win-7-64. I have seen a few suggestions online, but am quite concerned about two possible problems:

1. Having to carefully undo a load of changes to LAN settings. Some suggestions leave me with a feeling that I need an additional set of instructions for how to undo everything.
2. Having to share lots of directories and worrying that I may leave them exposed for the whole world to see once I'm connected back to the internet.

Can someone make a suggestion giving me reassurance that I won't run into trouble with either of my two concerns.

Comment: You can use a third party tool like [this](http://download.cnet.com/Easy-File-Sharing-FTP-Server/3000-2160_4-10386489.html) to setup a FTP Server or File Server. Other user can connect to this Server to download and upload files.

Answer (score 0):

If it is only for a temporary transfer of files, I would definitely recommend not changing your network settings, but look for an alternative transfer method, such as using an external flashdrive or harddrive.

If you decide to still look into lan, here are some interesting things to think about:

1. If you have a router that has DHCP enabled and both pc's are connected to one, it should often only be a matter of connecting the pc to the other router. The DHCP server will automatically give the pc the right IP address.
2. You can create a new folder on your harddrive, share it with "EVERYONE" or "NETWORK" for both read/write access, and when you're done, delete that folder and no one will have access to your whole pc.
3. When windows 7 detects a new network, set it to "Work environment" because that is the easiest way to undo. To change a network from home to work, do the following: Click the network icon in the taskbar, and choose `Open Network and Sharing center`. Cluck on the blue link that says Home Network (below View your active networks) And from the new dialog, choose Work network.
4. You do not have to place both pc's in the same workgroup. Just access the share using `\\pcname` and doubleclick the share.